# Safely use 10A Laptop charger Plug?

Tags: voltage, current, plug, socket

I have got an HP laptop charger who's plug has a marking "Linetek 10 A 250 V" over it.

[image]

On the other hand, the labeling says:

**Input: 100-240V ~50-60Hz 1.6A**
**Output: 19.5V  4.62A**

At home, I have got 230V supply and 50Hz.

As far as I know it's a "Type D" plug which plugs perfectly into 6 AMP Standard socket. Does the "10 A 250 V" refer to anything here I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple really, the marking on the plug refers to the plug.
So the plug (only the plug) can handle 10 A, 250 V. That does **not** mean that it **will** take 10A. It's just that it **can handle it**. The adapter detemines the current and it will take no more than 1.6 A.

The markings on the adapter refer to ... you guessed it, the adapter.
The adapter will take 100 - 240 V with a maximum of 1.6 A **as input**.
This is the rating for which it will operate. You could give it 90 V but then it is not guaranteed to work. It needs at least 100 V but no more than 240 V.
It will not take more than 1.6 A. So the plug is OK, since the plug can handle up to 10 A.

The adapter's output will be 19.5 V and the maximum current you can load it with is 4.62 A.

**So: stop being concerned !** What you have there is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

The ratings on the plug refer just to the maximum capability of the plug. The ratings on the charger are what are important. Your charger is capable of working correctly from 100V to 240V, from 50Hz to 60Hz, and the maximum possible current it can take froms the mains supply is 1.6A.

The charger will work OK from your 230V 50Hz supply.